# Polymer HTML Import caching

Tags: html, caching, import, version, polymer

I want to make sure that the browser gets the latest version of my custom elements via HMLT import. Right now, I am attaching a version query string:

e.g.

`<link rel="import" href="/dist/elements/my-element.html?v=12345">`

This is a common practice for JS and CSS files, and I am wondering if this is valid approach for HTML Imports as well?

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143776/polymer-disable-html-import-caching .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the same principles apply.

As an example, take a look at the source of http://www.polymer-project.org/. At the time of this writing, it contains `<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/elements/homepage_elements.vulcanized.html?20140828">`.

P.S. Described query parameter is not used at http://www.polymer-project.org/ anymore.

Comment: Could it be that is does not work with local import for example href="scheduler-event.html?1" does not seem to work. I get Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'scheduler-event'. A type with that name is already registered. If I remove the "?1" everything loads just fine.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to register `scheduler-event` twice, perhaps because you're importing both `scheduler-event.html` and `scheduler-event.html?1`? If that's what you're doing, don't. Just import `scheduler-event.html` once, with an optional query string you what appended to the URL.

Comment: This used to work, but as of polymer 0.5.4+, all the imports fail if I define a version query string parameter.

Comment: Currently running into the same issue with one of my elements (using polymer 0.5.4+).  I'd like to force a refresh of said element.  Any way to do that now?  Defining a version query string parameter doesn't seem to work.