# Polymer: Disable HTML Import caching

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, import, polymer

How do I disable HTML Import caching for Polymer development? Changes made to my custom HTML web component are not being shown when I refresh the browser.

Comment: What about caching issues on production? This is absolutely same thing there. And in most cases you just can't ask all users to clear cache or disable caching after new version deployment. Do you consider such issue?

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431641/polymer-html-import-caching .

Answer (score 4):

HTML Import caching will sometimes mean that changes made to HTML files that get imported do not get reflected upon browser refresh. Take the following import as an example:

```
<link rel="import" href="./my-element.html">
```

If a change is done to `my-element.html` after previously loading the page, then the changed file may not be downloaded and used in the current document when it is refreshed (as it was previously imported and cached). This can be great for a production, but might hinder development.

To disable this in Google Chrome:

- Open up Google Chrome's [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#access%20DevTools)
- Select the [Main Menu](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/settings?hl=en#main-menu%20settings) > Settings
- Go to the Network section
- Select "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"

This will avoid caching HTML Imports, but only when DevTools is open.

Comment: Simple but not really good solution. The way browser cache/refresh resources depends on headers passed from server. So it is possible to set-up server so that it will send changed resources even if browser cache is on. I.e. if you use polymer serve ([polymer-cli](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#serve)) you don't have to disable browser cache to see changes on refresh.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, that does sound better (if the setup cost doesn't outweigh the benefit that is). Could you post this as an answer along with the steps to achieve this please? Thanks